# Is the double "do" in the expression "If I do do it" more acceptable in spoken vs. written English?

Tags: phrase-usage, writing, speech

I'm a native English speaker from the Midwestern United States.  While writing a description to a colleague of some work that I recently did, I found myself typing a sentence to the effect of "I'd like to do [such-and-such] in the future, but I was able to get the main task done without it, so I'll do it separately if I do do it."

The double "do" seems a completely natural way of explaining this situation verbally, but it felt a bit awkward in writing.  A [Google search of the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+I+do+do+it%22) "if I do do it" has almost 8 million hits, so clearly this is a phrase that is said and written.  That said, while it feels like appropriate spoken English, it doesn't *feel* like appropriate written English.  It feels like something where it would be better to wordsmith the written text to sidestep this usage and use a different phrasing altogether.  For instance, I feel myself more inclined to write "if I do end up doing it" instead.

Is my intuition that this is generally acceptable in spoken English but not in written English accurate?  Is there something special about this double-do phrasing, or am I just overthinking this?

Note that I do see a similar question about the double "do" ([Does it sound weird if I say I do do sports during the week?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453165/does-it-sound-weird-if-i-say-i-do-do-sports-during-the-week)), though it doesn't address whether it's a written vs. spoken thing.

Comment: This seems like a matter of opinion. *My* opinion is "if I do do it" is fine in that context whether spoken or written. Obviously if you're not comfortable with it you can phrase it differently.

Comment: "What if I don't do it?" Do you have a problem with that? It's the same construction as "What if I do do it?" — only negated.

Comment: @Robusto "Don't [verb]" appears to be the way to negate a verb, whereas "Do [verb]" is just redundant.  If the main verb of the sentence is "do", I'm not sure there's a way to get around the preceding "don't" without switching to a different action verb.  e.g. "If I do fly" is the same (with different level of emphasis) as "If I fly", whereas the "don't" is necessary for the meaning of the sentence in "If I don't fly" or "If I don't do it", and can't be dropped.

Comment: @M.Justin: It's a matter of emphasis. If your criterion is that this appears to be wrong then this question is opinion-based. Voting to close.

Comment: If study = do study, and its negative is 'do not study/ don't study', or go = do go/ don't go, 'do' can be do do (neg. do not do/ don't do) is acceptable. The point is how frequently one uses it.

Comment: @Robusto I also feel like "cat" appears to be a word in the English language, but that's something that can easily be backed up by facts, so I certainly wouldn't call it "opinion-based" because of that.  I'm not looking for an opinion-based answer, just wondering whether or not my intuition matches up with established facts on English language usage.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've been taught, using the emphatic do in really formal writing like "I do think the author intends to..." takes aware from its style, most of the time it is unnecessary. For example "If I do it" and "If I do do it" have the exact same meaning, just one reinforces more so than the other the actual act of "doing it" so it's almost a form of tautology. So I would say, if you're writing some sort of literature paper or academic article and you really want a formal, almost uptight tone, don't use the emphatic do.

Comment: "Emphatic 'do'"… Thanks for giving me some terminology.  I wasn't sure how to refer to this other than just give the "do do" phrase.